# svn local obstruction, incoming add upon merge

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have read quite a few SO threads on this and also the following ***[blogg](http://little418.com/2009/05/svn-local-obstruction-incoming-add-upon-merge.html)*** but still don't understand my particular issue so I hope someone can help...

Doing a merge from mainline into dev line to catch up again and I get the following tree conflict.

```
M      incubator
     C incubator/UtilityScripts
     >   local dir obstruction, incoming dir add upon merge
```

Okay, so I understand that this should be that this directory was independently added to both the trunk and dev branch independently such that there is no common ancestor...

..Buuuut (there's always a but right?!) there IS a common ancestor. This directory entered my dev branch because of a previous merge from truck.

```
dev$ svn mergeinfo {^/trunk/src/,}incubator/UtilityScripts/
     youngest common ancestor
     |         last full merge
     |         |        tip of branch
     |         |        |         repository path

     23788              23838   
     |                  |       
   -------| |------------         trunk/src/incubator/UtilityScripts
      \                         
       \                        
       --| |------------          branches/dev/src/incubator/UtilityScripts

                        |       
                        23838
```

So, as I understand this SVN does believe that the dev branch is ancestrally related to trunk with a common ancestor at revision 23788.

```
branch$ svn log --stop-on-copy incubator/UtilityScripts/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r23790 | me | 2015-05-12 16:08:25 +0100 (Tue, 12 May 2015) | 1 line
```

So I got this file in revision 23790 and I am now at revision 23838

```
Trunk$ svn log --stop-on-copy incubator/UtilityScripts/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r23639 | someone | 2015-03-06 10:59:10 +0000 (Fri, 06 Mar 2015) | 1 line
```

So, common ancestor is 23788. The only revision at which this entered my dev branch as 23790 which is after this anyway.The most recent trunk change is 23639 which is before any of these.

So given this, how on earth can there be an incoming add conflict?!